# C++ fstream how to skip a line?

Tags: c++, fstream

I know how to open file and read it but I need help skipping line. For example like this

---

1. Tom Atto
2. 6
3. 11
4. Carky oki
5. 4
6. 9

---

I want to store 6 and 4 into one variable and 11 and 9 into other variable. I was tasked to create a program that takes the height of a person and solve it to get their ideal body weight. Also, just wondering is there a way to get every name, then the ft, and finally inches? there's a pattern in the list. It begins with a name followed by ft then inches then name again.

Comment: if you can read line by line, what's stopping you from putting each line in a different variable?

Comment: i word it  wrong,  I ment i know how to open it and only print out the content of it. but idk how to assign the conent into a variable

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand where you're getting stuck. When you read a line where do you usually put it? I don't think you `cout` it directly, do you?

Comment: Im using while(Data_file >> name) then i print out all the names and the numbers. so it prints out Tom Atto 6 11 Carky oki 4 9. What I want to do is get  6 and 4 and assign to a integer name Feet and get 11 and 9 and assign it to Inches

Comment: Ok, what if, instead of putting everything inside `name` you first do `Data_file>>name` than `Data_file>>ft` and finally `Data_file>>inches` and do that as long as `Data_file` returns stuff?

Comment: Note: this is assuming name is just one word, without spaces (which it's not), but it should nudge you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You know the fist line is a name(1st, 2nd name) and after every name you have 2 line of value

```
string Fname, Lname;
int inchVlaue, ftValue;

ifstream myFile("name.txt");

while(myFile.peek() != EOF)
{
    myFile >> Fame;
    myFile >> Lname;
    myFile >> inchVlaue;
    myFile >> ftValue;


}
```

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz perhaps you should state why or give a reference/link

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part of your question that you asked here:

> Also, just wondering is there a way to get every name, then the ft, and finally inches? there's a pattern in the list. It begins with a name followed by ft then inches then name again.

This should get all the data considering the pattern shown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Person {
    std::string name_;
    unsigned feet_;
    unsigned inches_;

    Person() 
      : feet_(0), inches_(0) {}
    Person( const std::string& name, const unsigned& feet, const unsigned& inches )
      : name_(name), feet_(feet), inches_(inches) {}
};

int main() {
    std::string filename( "somefilename.txt" );
    std::ifstream fileIn;

    // Temps -
    std::string name;
    unsigned feet   = 0;
    unsigned inches = 0;

    std::vector<Person> people;

    fileIn.open( filename.c_str() ); 

    while ( fileIn >> name >> feet >> inches ) {
        Person person( name, feet, inches );
        people.push_back( person );
    }

    if ( fileIn.is_open() ) {
        fileIn.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As for skipping a line; if you know what line or lines to skip; you can now just check your vector to see what needs to be eliminated or disregarded.

**EDIT**

Without running the above code in my compiler and off the top of my mind I can not remember if the first read in the while loop for the string will only get the first set of characters for the first name only or if it will get the whole line until the return or newline character. I did not type this out in my IDE as I currently don't have it available atm. If this tends to be a problem you will need to modify the struct to have a second string for the last name and to add a second temp variable, and to add the second string to the while loop before the first unsigned as well as adding it to the structs constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If You have an pattern, You also have opportunity to use temporary `std::string` which represent name and [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex), which will be find values.
I mean:

```
std::regex nameReg("([[:alpha:]]){1,}") // for name
std::regex numReg("([0-9]{1,})") // for ft
```

You need an loop where conditions will be find and swap temporary name.
It's may be overkill :), but it's common and universal solution

Answer (score 0):

You could have a little function like

```
inline std::istream&swallow_rest_of_line(std::istream& from)
{
    char c;
    do from.get(c); while(from.good() && c !='\n');
    return from;
}
```

to skip lines